# Убунта 16.10. Программы не устанавливаются :(

Tags: ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить [ANoise](http://anoise.tuxfamily.org/), делаю всё как там указано и в результате:

```
Ошк:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu yakkety Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Данные из этого репозитория нельзя аутентифицировать, и поэтому потенциально из небезопасно использовать.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

Точно такая же проблема с [OpenXcom](http://openxcom.org/downloads-milestones/). Пытался скачать deb-пакеты отдельно из репозитория и установить вручную - у ANoise неразрешённые зависимости, OpenXcom установился, но не запускается.

**UPD:**

Попробовал заменить yakkety на xenial, обновил - всё успешно, а при попытке установить вылазит такая ошибка:

```
winterwolf@MAINFRAME:~$ sudo apt-get install anoise
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 anoise : Зависит: python-gst0.10 но он не может быть установлен
          Зависит: gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 но он не может быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Comment: ну нету сборок для вашей версии (цифрами: 16.10, словами: yakkety): http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: Это я как бы понял, но что в таких случаях обычно делают? Я когда качал последнюю версию, меня никто не предупредил что на неё нет софта, который меня интересует! Бред какой-то. Это мне нужно теперь всё сносить и  ставить более старую систему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ошк:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
>     404  Not Found

нет сборок, выполненных для вашей версии дистрибутива (кодовое имя *yakkety*):

```
$ w3m -dump http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu/dists/
Index of /costales/anoise/ubuntu/dists

[ICO]       Name         Last modified   Size Description
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
[DIR] Parent Directory                      -  
[DIR] devel/           23-Jan-2016 18:59    -  
[DIR] precise/         23-Oct-2015 17:54    -  
[DIR] trusty/          23-Oct-2015 17:34    -  
[DIR] utopic/          01-Apr-2015 21:23    -  
[DIR] vivid/           23-Oct-2015 17:54    -  
[DIR] wily/            23-Oct-2015 17:54    -  
[DIR] xenial/          23-Jan-2016 18:59    -  
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

**первое**, что можно попробовать сделать — использовать репозиторий ближайшей версии, для которой сборка имеется. насколько я понимаю, это версия с кодовым именем *xenial*:

1. замените в строке, где подключен этот репозиторий, слово `yakkety` на `xenial` (строка начинается со слова `deb`, а дальше весьма схожа с тем, что написано в процитированном сообщении об ошибке). найти файл, где репозиторий подключен, можно примерно так:

   ```
   $ grep -rl costales/anoise /etc/apt/sources.list*
   ```
2. обновите список пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. и вновь попробуйте установить пакет:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install anoise
   ```

---

**второе** (из простых вариантов), что можно попробовать — установить ту версию дистрибутива, для которой можно найти собранные сторонние пакеты *с большей вероятностью*. в случае дистрибутива *ubuntu* (и его вариаций) — это т.н. [*lts-версии*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) (long term support). на данный момент самая новая lts-версия — 16.04

---

**третье**, что можно попробовать *в данном случа* (в случае, если первый вариант закончился неудовлетворёнными зависимостями, а второй, например, нежелателен) — установить пакет принудительно:

1. скачать пакет в текущий каталог:

   ```
   $ apt-get download имя.пакета
   ```
2. попробовать распаковать полученный файл с помощью низкоуровнего средства — *dpkg*, игнорируя зависимости:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg --install --no-force-depends файл.с.пакетом
   ```

   и получить список неудовлетворённых зависимостей, например, где-то такой:

   ```
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of anoise:
    anoise depends on python-gst0.10; however:
     Package python-gst0.10 is not installed.
    anoise depends on gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10; however:
     Package gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 is not installed.
    anoise depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0; however:
     Package gir1.2-gtk-3.0 is not installed.
    anoise depends on anoise-media; however:
     Package anoise-media is not installed.
   ```
3. после чего распаковать уже без этих зависимостей, перечислив их в опции `--ignore-depends=`:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg --install --ignore-depends=python-gst0.10,gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10,gir1.2-gtk-3.0,anoise-media файл.с.пакетом
   ```

   в результате пакет-то будет, вроде бы, «установлен», но, ввиду отсутствия зависимостей, программы из него не заработают (не будут запускаться вообще, или будут «падать»).

   если вам удастся подобрать (и, главное, установить) пакеты, которые обладают требуемой функциональностью (близкие по имени пакеты, пакеты из предыдущих версий дистрибутива и т.д. и т.п.) — вам повезло. можете при установке «старых» пакетов использовать тот же трюк: «скачать, затем распаковать с помощью dpkg».

**четвёртое**, что можно попробовать — это пересобрать пакет самостоятельно под пакетную базу вашей версии дистрибутива. описание этого процесса (и всех трудностей, с которыми вы столкнётесь при попытке подобрать замены несуществующим зависимостям) уже явно выходит за рамки текущего ответа. поисковый запрос в помощь: [ubuntu пересобрать пакет](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ubuntu%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82)

Comment: Не помогло. Пишет "возможно, вы просите невозможного".

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, простые варианты на этом, увы, практически заканчиваются, а начинается множество разных более сложных вариантов. последний оставшийся простой вариант: установить lte-версию дистрибутива .

Comment: Только самый последний LTS - это Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Jenyay, я черпал информацию с указанной страницы, которую первой выдаёт, например, гугль, на запрос «*ubuntu lts*». спасибо за уточнение, буду дописывать ответ, внесу корректировку.

Answer (score 0):

Крепление окружающего шума для Ubuntu 16.10 требуется сейчас для компиляции из исходных текстов приложение.

Выполните эти команды в оболочку, установив сначала зависимостей:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 python-gst-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 python-distutils-extra gir1.2-webkit-3.0
```

Звуковой индикатор:

```
bzr branch lp:anoise
cd anoise
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr
```

Звуки:

```
bzr branch lp:~costales/anoise/media
cd media
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr
```

Если у вас есть игрок в индикаторе звука, это делается! Если нет, то установите GUI:

```
bzr branch lp:~costales/anoise/anoise-gui
cd anoise-gui
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr
```

Теперь вы можете запустить anoise вид терминала

```
anoise &
```

или из меню. Наслаждайтесь!